# Use a variable to call a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity framework to manipulate a data base, and I was wondering if I could used a variable to call a method

I tried with this way:

```
string name = "tableName";
db.[name].AddRange(dates.[name]);
```

but it didn't work

I want to call a method of this way because I'm going to do multiples inserts in different tables. and I have in mind use an array or some collection with all the names of the tables.

and then iterate the collection

```
public ActionResult MetodoRecibe(Reporte datas)
{
   string name = "tableName";
   db.tableName.AddRange(datos.tableName);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return Json(datas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

My variable data is Json with the following structure:

```
datas{
nameTable1[],
nameTable2[],
nameTable3[],
.
.
.
.
nameTable13
}
```

I had considered using a `switch case` as a last resort but because of the quantity of tables I would prefer to use the first option.

Comment: If you need an AddRange() functionality and don't want to use a traditional loop, try creating an extension method AddRange<T> that will do what you want.

Comment: You could use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection). Another way is to create a dictionary that allows you to call specific delegate by table name.

Comment: EF6 that say at .Conttext.tt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use reflection for doing such operation.
Try like following:

```
public ActionResult MetodoRecibe(Reporte datas)
{
  string name = "TableName"; // This has to be exact with EF entity name
  var type = ((IQueryable)efContext.GetType().GetProperty("TableName").GetValue(efContext)).ElementType;
  var dbSet = efContext.Set(type); 
  dbset.AddRange(dates.[name]);
  efContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I tried with this way but it give me the next error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Report.Models.ParosLinea]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'.'


`code` public virtual DbSet<ParosLinea> ParosLineas { get; set; }

i tried with this method of my db or entity context 

this is the code that give me error:
`code` var dbset = (System.Data.Entity.DbSet)db.GetType().GetProperty("ParosLineas").GetValue(db);

Comment: @JohnatanDeLeon What about this exception?

Comment: I found a solution, I made something like this:

`code`                 var type = ((IQueryable)db.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(db))
                .ElementType;
                var dbSet = db.Set(type);

Comment: @JohnatanDeLeon I am updating the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand very well the idea behind what you are doing, but I guess you want to call a method by a string. You can do this through reflection.

Something like

```
MethodInfo myFunc = GetType().GetMethod("MyMethodName");
myFunc.Invoke(this, <MyMethodName arguments>);
```

Answer (score 0):

EF core's `DbContext` has an `AddRange<T>` method, EF6's not. But of course it's fairly easy to add one, or a couple:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    // In case your nameTable1[] arrays are of type object[]
    public void AddRange(params object[] data)
    {
        if (!data.Any()) return;

        var entityType = data[0].GetType();
        Set(entityType).AddRange(data);
    }

    public void AddRange<T>(params T[] data)
        where T : class
    {
        Set<T>().AddRange(data);
    }

    public void AddRange<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        where T : class
    {
        Set<T>().AddRange(data);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm a Junior developer in addition I have a little time programing in C# and the truth is that I don't understand your answer, I'm really sorry.
Could you explain me how can I use these methods to make something like this: 
`code`(myDbContext.[variableWithNameOfTable].where(x  => x.foreignKey == someNumber).select(all))
I can use Entity core where I work

Comment: You can use the first method to add a collection of objects of which you don't know the type, that is, the result of your statement `myDbContext.[variableWithNameOfTable]...`. However, I think that sooner or later you'll learn that you better abandon this untyped approach, but that's beyond the scope of this question & answer.

Comment: what is your recommendation. I'm going to make the same query to different tables; SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FOREIGN_KEY = ANY_NUMBER 

I'm going to make the same query to table2, table3, table4............ table11


and in the proccess build a json like this 
datos{
table1[],
table2[],
table3[],
.
.
.
table11[]
}

Comment: Please ask this in another question. It's too much to do this in comments. When asking a new question make sure to paint the bigger picture: what are you trying to achieve in a wider sense? Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a better place to ask such a question, if you have working code and are willing to share enough for a decent review.

Comment: i have made a new post this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662134/make-the-same-select-to-differents-table-using-entity-framework-and-linq