# Dynamically get a DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to get a `DbSet` with the class name that I have stored in a variable.

I have tried with this code:

```
string name = "ParosLineas";
var dbset = (System.Data.Entity.DbSet)efContext.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(efContext);

dbset.AddRange(dates.[name]);
efContext.SaveChanges();
```

but I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet1[Report.Models.ParosLinea]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

this is my ParosLine declaration:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `ParosLineas`?

Comment: I have did it !

Comment: I [answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57543487/861716) in your previous question, but apparently you didn't notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the generic [DbSet<TEntity>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) class does not inherit (hence cannot be cast to) the non generic [DbSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

I see two options.

If you know the namespace name of the entity class, you can use `Type.GetType` to get the corresponding `Type` which in turn can be used to call the non generic [DbContext.Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method which returns a non generic `DbSet` object, e.g.

```
string nameSpace = "MyEntities";
string name = "ParosLineas";
var type = Type.GetType($"{namespace}.{name}");
var dbSet = efContext.Set(type);
```

Another way is to use reflection to get the `DbSet<T>` property as you are doung, but cast the result to `IQueryable`. Then you can use the `IQueryable.ElementType` to call the non generic `Set` method as above:

```
string name = "ParosLineas";
var type = ((IQueryable)efContext.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(efContext))
    .ElementType;
var dbSet = db.Set(type);
```

The first method is preferable. First, because it uses less calls, and second, because does not require `DbSet<T>` property in the context and does not assume that `DbSet<T>` property name is the same as the entity class name.

Comment: I use the second option and it worked!
Thanks a lot! I'm really  really grateful! You are the best

Comment: Hi @Ivan Stoev I hope you response my comment. I'm making a CRUD, that is the reason why I wanted to make a insert using reflection.
Now i want to make a select with the same way. I'm trying to make something like:
SELECT *
FROM any Table
WHRE foreign Key = any number
I want to make this using linq and reflection. having the name of table that i want to manipulate in a string variable is it possible?

Comment: Everything is possible (to some sort of extent). The good thing for querying is that all you need is `IQueryable`. The bad thing is that almost all out of the box LINQ methods are for the generic `IQueryable<T>` and not for `IQueryable`. So you have to use a lot of reflection and manual expression building. 3rd party packages like [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#microsoftentityframeworkcoredynamiclinq) might help.

Comment: DbContext in Entity Framework Core 6.0 does not have a .Set() method that takes a type as parameter. You have to use `dbContext.Find(type, id)`.