# Get data from database table by string Name of table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have c# config where I have name of table or view and field from where I need to get data.

Here is setting part

```
  new()
        {
            DisplayIndex = 1082,
            FieldNameDomain = nameof(VwScoringJobSupplier.SchemeIdentifications),
            Label = "Identifications",
            DataType = "string",
            Group = "Attributes",
            IsAnalysisFilter = false,
            IsUseCaseFilter = false,
            FilterType = "multiselect",
            IsAvailableForScoringAdmin = false,
            Source = "VwScoringJobSuppliers"
        },
```

`FieldNameDomain` is name of field, `Source` is table or view

I need to get name data from this view(table) from specific field in code like this

```
private async Task<List<OptionDto>> GetOptions(Guid jobId, string source, string field)
{
   var options = await _dbContext.VwScoringJobSuppliers.Distinct().Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
        .Select(x => x.State).ToListAsync();
}
```

But table or view and field in select must come from strings `source` and `field`

How I can achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I can get dbSet like this

```
public static PropertyInfo GetDbSetProperty(Type typeOfEntity, ScoringDbContext context)
{
    var genericDbSetType = typeof(DbSet<>);
    // typeof(DbSet<User.Role>);
    var entityDbSetType = genericDbSetType.MakeGenericType(typeOfEntity);

    // DbContext type
    var contextType = context.GetType();

    return contextType
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType == entityDbSetType)
        .FirstOrDefault();      
}
```

But how I can then add it to

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
.FromSqlRaw("SELECT {0} FROM dbo.{1}", source, field)
.ToList();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Raw SQL Queries

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT {0} FROM dbo.{1}", source, field)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543232/dynamically-get-a-dbset you can get a dbset here

Comment: Which efcore version are you using?