# Make the same select to different tables using Entity Framework and Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Ok! I'm going to explain what I don't want to do:

I'm making a report, this report is conformed by multiples tables:[image]

this is the entity relation diagram of my data base. I have a Json like this in my front-end:

```
var json = {
  DatesReport: [],
  Maquinas: [],
  Faltantes: [],
   ParosLinea: [],
   Reinsertos:[],
   Auditado: [],
  Pendientes: [],
  TiempoExtra: [],
  Scrap: [],
  Criticos: [],
  Accidentes: []
};
```

I already have the logic to fill this Json and then send this one to my back-end.

[image]

This is my method that receives the json of from front-end to back-end then insert all values at this way

this is my class reporte:
[image]

So my problem is that I don't find the way to make something similar to what I already have to insert all data of all different tables

I'm looking for a way to make a select at all different tables in my back-end, form my json and sent it to my front-end

I Could made with this way:
[image]

But I'm looking for the best way to make it, I'm trying to make my code short, and Maintainable

in addition this is my dbcontext
[image]

Comment: FYI JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It is the syntax used to store javascript objects as plain text to store/transport them. If you are working with code you are working with Javascript objects, not JSON.

Comment: You need to take a look at C# Generics. I'm sure there are better ways to do what you're trying to do though. How are you sending the arrays from the front-end? Is it via a form or are you calling an Api?

Comment: It would help to know the use case. What is the goal of this part of the application? If you give some more background we can give better suggestions how to improve your approach. I feel that somehow you should get rid of this untyped code, but without knowing what it's supposed to do it's hard to give any useful directions.

Comment: Also: show the Entity Framework class model. And do all tables have the same foreign key? I.e. pointing to the same referred table?

Comment: I have edited mi question I hope someone can help me, I have a few days looking the best way to make this and I don't find it

Comment: If you're basing your classes on the ERD then your `Reportes` class should only have a `DatesReporte` in it. The `DatesReporte` class should then contain the list of arrays. The same goes for the javascript object. You're trying to create a hierarchy as a flat model without any mapping between the layers. What does the JSON you're returning look like? EF will deal with your relationships when adding data if you send it in the correct format. You don't need to add to each individual table manually.

Comment: Next time, please add code as text. Makes it easier to search it and to copy/paste parts for answering.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to keep the types of the tables in a List and then iterate e.g.

```
    List<Type> types = new List<Type>{ typeof(FirstTableType), typeof(SecondTableType) };
    foreach(Type type in types) 
    {
        var searchedEntities = dbContext.Set(type).Where(x => (x as AbstractClass).foreignKey == searchNumber);
        // The rest of your logic
    }
```

But that would still require you to write all of the types at least once.
It would also **require all of the types to have a property named foreignKey** (either through an interface or an abstract class).

You could check up on the documentation for Entity Framework's DbContext class for other options.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: I tried with this way but It give me the next error:

dbSet does not contain a definition for where and no accessible extension method

Comment: Please make sure there is a "using System.Linq;" in the usings section of the class in which you are writing this code. I see no other reason for the "Where" method to not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the database model you should have a class `DatesReport` that contains all collections. So instead of a Json object like...

> ```
> {
>   DatesReport: [],
>   Maquinas: [],
>   Faltantes: [],
>   ParosLinea: [],
>   Reinsertos:[],
>   Auditado: [],
>   Pendientes: [],
>   TiempoExtra: [],
>   Scrap: [],
>   Criticos: [],
>   Accidentes: []
> }
> ```

...there should be a class looking like...

```cs
class DatesReport
{
    public int IdReport { get; set; }
    ... more properties

    public ICollection<Maquina> Maquinas { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Faltante> Faltantes { get; set; }
    ... etc.

}
```

And in the context a property...

```cs
public DbSet<DatesReport> Reports { get; set; }
```

Now you can get the data you want by only one Where condition:

```
var report = context.Reports
    .Include(r => r.Maquinas)
    .Include(r => r.Faltantes)
    ... etc
    .Single(r => r.Id == id)
```

The serialized `report` will look different than the Json you have now, but the UI code should be able to handle that. Likewise, it should return a `DatesReport` object containing these collections. If it does, adding a new report gets very simple:

```cs
context.Reports.Add(report);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Where `report` is the report object that enters the action method `MetodoRecibe` instead of the `datos` object. It will add the report and all contained collections in one go.